# How do I enable HTTPS for a Container Instance on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-container-instances

I've got a nodejs app running inside docker on a container instance in Azure.

I have a URL which is an IP address with HTTP only.

e.g.

```
http://123.456.789
```

I need it to be HTTPS because it is providing content to a React frontend and therefore I have a mixed content issue.

The App services on Azure just works by adding a https to the front of the address, but these are different and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Not been able to get it work Nancy

Answer (score 1):

You could add an extra sidecar container running the public Nginx image, configured to use TLS. Read [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl) to enable a TLS endpoint in a sidecar container and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958057/how-to-add-ssl-to-azure-container-instance-app) for more choices. If you want to automatic HTTPS with Azure Container Instances (ACI) with terraform, you could refer to [this](https://itnext.io/automatic-https-with-azure-container-instances-aci-4c4c8b03e8c9).