# azure container instance running on private network with domain

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-container-instances

I have an ACI running on a private network, there I have my application, my application needs to run on HTTPS protocol for that I need a certificate but I can't add a domain to my container to be able to generate the certificate

Comment: Hi Leandro Salamaia, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Https support for azure container instances has been discussed here before, and this question has a good answer. Does it tell you what you need to know? [How to add SSL to Azure Container Instance App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958057/how-to-add-ssl-to-azure-container-instance-app)

Answer (score 0):

Azure Container Instances does not have any option to add the custom domain to your instance

If you want to map custom domain to your Azure Container instance, you can create a CNAME record in your domain to redirect it to the ACI FQDN

Still, you would be facing the issue of SSL if your custom domain does not have SSL

You need to add the SSL certificate to your domain, then the requests from your custom domain will be redirected to your ACI FQDN

As you are using Virtual Network for your ACI, you need to whitelist your custom domain in the Virtual Network