# Azure Container Instance Http to Https

Tags: azure-devops, https, ssl-certificate, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I have SonarQube running in an Azure Container Instance that is not in a container registry. I'm trying to change the FQDN from Http to Https; however, all of the examples I see only provide instructions for using a registry. Is there a way to do this without using a ACR?

Answer (score 0):

***Yes, This could be possible withou using ACR and with enabling SSL connections in a sidecar container.***

ACI does not have a built in support for https. However, to enable a ssl connection you will need a webserver in your container with the required certs refer  [sidecar container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl)  or front your container with an application gateway. You can also consider using app service or kubernetes for achieving this.

For security advice see  [Azure security baseline for Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/security-baseline).

Please check similar issue on  [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958057/how-to-add-ssl-to-azure-container-instance-app)  which has more information.

******Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/50827/container-instance-dns-using-http-and-not-https.html******

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to make sure I'm clear, I can do this without interfering with the running instance of SonarQube. I can add the sidecar container without taking it down and creating a new instance right? We're already using SonarQube and I do not want to stop it or take it down.